# How to create a boxplot for summary table with counts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, summary

I have a summary table with counts of scores for two groups. I want to create a box plot to get the distribution, mean, SD of the scores.

I see examples with datasets with the values listed. The dataset I am working with is the summarized counts of the scores. How would I go about creating a box plot so that I can see what the score spread over the two groups look like.

Here is the sample data:

```
    score  count_new count_prev
 1:     0    1   48
 2:     1   NA   13
 3:     2    1  412
 4:     3   NA  237
 5:     4   NA  169
 6:     5    2   88
 7:     6 1026   60
 8:     7  587   50
 9:     8  471   28
10:     9  266   22
11:    10  181   10
12:    11  115    5
13:    12   67    2
14:    13   34   NA
15:    14   15   NA
16:    15    8    1
17:    16    6   NA
18:    17    2   NA

structure(list(score = 0:17, count_new = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 
1026L, 587L, 471L, 266L, 181L, 115L, 67L, 34L, 15L, 8L, 6L, 2L
), count_prev = c(48L, 13L, 412L, 237L, 169L, 88L, 60L, 50L, 28L, 22L, 
10L, 5L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Here is the mean and SD for each group. I am trying to see how the scores are distributed.

```
     sd avg grp
1: 1.88   7  new
2: 2.11   3  prev
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could regenerate the original data according to the counts in each category:

```
# Replace NAs by Os
data[is.na(data$count_new),"count_new"]<-0
data[is.na(data$count_prev),"count_prev"]<-0

# Regenerate data according to counts
new <- data$score[rep(1:nrow(data), data$count_new)]
prev <- data$score[rep(1:nrow(data), data$count_prev)]
regenerated <- data.frame(type=c(rep("prev",length(prev)),rep("new",length(new))),
                          value =c(prev,new))

sd(prev)
#[1] 2.110576
sd(new)
#[1] 1.881819
mean(prev)
#[1] 3.484716
mean(new)
#[1] 7.627606

boxplot(value~type,data=regenerated)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Regenerate the original scores using `uncount()`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

counts <- structure(list(score = 0:17, count_new = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 
                                           1026L, 587L, 471L, 266L, 181L, 115L, 67L, 34L, 15L, 8L, 6L, 2L
), count_prev = c(48L, 13L, 412L, 237L, 169L, 88L, 60L, 50L, 28L, 22L, 
                  10L, 5L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                  ), row.names = c(NA, -18L))

count_new <- counts %>% 
  select(-count_prev) %>% 
  mutate(count_new = ifelse(is.na(count_new), 0, count_new)) %>% 
  uncount(count_new)

count_prev <- counts %>% 
  select(-count_new) %>% 
  mutate(count_prev = ifelse(is.na(count_prev), 0, count_prev)) %>% 
  uncount(count_prev)

bind_rows(count_new, count_prev, .id = "when") %>% 
  mutate(when = factor(when, labels = c("new", "prev"))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(when, score))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `pivot_longer` to render your dataframe in correct format for plotting:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(score = 0:17, 
                     new = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 1026L, 587L, 471L, 266L, 
                             181L, 115L, 67L, 34L, 15L, 8L, 6L, 2L), 
                     prev = c(48L, 13L, 412L, 237L, 169L, 88L, 60L, 50L, 28L, 
                              22L, 10L, 5L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), 
                class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -18L)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c("new", "prev"))

boxplot(value ~ name, data = df)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I m not sure this is what I am looking for. Just doing the simple math I can calculate the mean and SD for the groups . I am trying to see the distribution of the scores.
sd avg grp ->
1.88   7   new /
2.11   3   prev

Answer (score 1):

#### New answer

I am not completely sure what you exactly want. Maybe you want something like this:

```
boxplot(df$score, horizontal = TRUE, staplewex = 1, xlab = "Scores", main = "Boxplot")
text(x=fivenum(df$score), labels =fivenum(df$score), y=1.25)
```

Output:

[image]

Your mean is the same as your median:

```
> mean(df$score)
[1] 8.5
```

#### Old answer

You can create two `geom_boxplot` like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = "new", y = new)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = "prev", y = prev)) +
  labs(x = "groups", y = "count") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for. I am trying to get the distribution and quartile spread of the scores. What I have in my dataset is the count of the scores.

Comment: @utsabshrestha, added new answer.